# Blazor WebAssembly Loading Azure Storage Blobs issue: Response x-ms-client-request-id '' does not match the original expected request id ''

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, blazor

I am creating a Blazor webassembly app that loads an azure blob json file and then displays it.

I have access to the Storage Account using AzureAd and an additional scope. I can list and see the blob using BlobContainerClient that uses a custom Credential to read the Access Token, but when I try to download the blob I get errors:

Working code to list the blobs by name:

```cs
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            var accountUri = new Uri("https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer");
            var client = new BlobContainerClient(accountUri, Credential);

            Blobs = new List<string>();

            await foreach (var blobItem in client.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: "json/"))
            {
                Blobs.Add(blobItem.Name);
            }
        }
```

However the code that isn't working is as follows:

```cs
        protected BlobDownloadInfo Blob;

...

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            var accountUri = new Uri("https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer");
            var client = new BlobContainerClient(accountUri, Credential);

            var blobClient = client.GetBlockBlobClient(Storage.Data);

            Blob = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
        }
```

This throws the following exception on which I couldn't find anything when seacrhing the web:

```
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Response x-ms-client-request-id '82d5f0bb-bd83-4ef5-8f3a-fa5165f4737a' does not match the original expected request id, 'fcacef5f-0472-44c7-b36d-bafdf2768451'.
      Status: 200 (OK)
      
      Headers:
      Accept-Ranges: bytes
      Date: Mon, 06 Jul 2020 19:18:05 GMT
      ETag: "0x8D82021DE355DD6"
      Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
      x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
      x-ms-client-request-id: 82d5f0bb-bd83-4ef5-8f3a-fa5165f4737a
      x-ms-creation-time: Sat, 04 Jul 2020 13:55:10 GMT
      x-ms-lease-state: available
      x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
      x-ms-request-id: e415a9cd-001e-000b-7dca-53dfb7000000
      x-ms-server-encrypted: true
      x-ms-version: 2019-07-07
      Content-Length: 1284435
      Content-MD5: uQBQz3kRBFQgZPSAcV27LA==
      Content-Type: application/json
      Last-Modified: Sat, 04 Jul 2020 13:55:10 GMT
      
Azure.RequestFailedException: Response x-ms-client-request-id '82d5f0bb-bd83-4ef5-8f3a-fa5165f4737a' does not match the original expected request id, 'fcacef5f-0472-44c7-b36d-bafdf2768451'.
Status: 200 (OK)

Headers:
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 06 Jul 2020 19:18:05 GMT
ETag: "0x8D82021DE355DD6"
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
x-ms-client-request-id: 82d5f0bb-bd83-4ef5-8f3a-fa5165f4737a
x-ms-creation-time: Sat, 04 Jul 2020 13:55:10 GMT
x-ms-lease-state: available
x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
x-ms-request-id: e415a9cd-001e-000b-7dca-53dfb7000000
x-ms-server-encrypted: true
x-ms-version: 2019-07-07
Content-Length: 1284435
Content-MD5: uQBQz3kRBFQgZPSAcV27LA==
Content-Type: application/json
Last-Modified: Sat, 04 Jul 2020 13:55:10 GMT

  at Azure.Storage.StorageRequestValidationPipelinePolicy.OnReceivedResponse (Azure.Core.HttpMessage message) <0x34b6270 + 0x000d2> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.ProcessAsync (Azure.Core.HttpMessage message, System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[T] pipeline) <0x33c0748 + 0x00114> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync (Azure.Core.HttpMessage message, System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[T] pipeline, System.Boolean async) <0x33a8080 + 0x0012c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync (Azure.Core.HttpMessage message, System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[T] pipeline, System.Boolean async) <0x33a8080 + 0x00270> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.ProcessAsync (Azure.Core.HttpMessage message, System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[T] pipeline) <0x33c0748 + 0x00100> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.ProcessAsync (Azure.Core.HttpMessage message, System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[T] pipeline) <0x33c0748 + 0x00100> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.ProcessAsync (Azure.Core.HttpMessage message, System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[T] pipeline) <0x33c0748 + 0x00100> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient+Blob.DownloadAsync (Azure.Core.Pipeline.ClientDiagnostics clientDiagnostics, Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipeline pipeline, System.Uri resourceUri, System.String version, System.String snapshot, System.Nullable`1[T] timeout, System.String range, System.String leaseId, System.Nullable`1[T] rangeGetContentHash, System.Nullable`1[T] rangeGetContentCRC64, System.String encryptionKey, System.String encryptionKeySha256, System.Nullable`1[T] encryptionAlgorithm, System.Nullable`1[T] ifModifiedSince, System.Nullable`1[T] ifUnmodifiedSince, System.Nullable`1[T] ifMatch, System.Nullable`1[T] ifNoneMatch, System.String requestId, System.Boolean async, System.String operationName, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x35b43e0 + 0x002c6> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () <0x35cfde8 + 0x0003c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.StartDownloadAsync (Azure.HttpRange range, Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobRequestConditions conditions, System.Boolean rangeGetContentHash, System.Int64 startOffset, System.Boolean async, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x35b2e50 + 0x004be> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadInternal (Azure.HttpRange range, Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobRequestConditions conditions, System.Boolean rangeGetContentHash, System.Boolean async, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x35aaeb0 + 0x002b8> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadAsync (Azure.HttpRange range, Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobRequestConditions conditions, System.Boolean rangeGetContentHash, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x35a2830 + 0x000fa> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x35a20c8 + 0x000fc> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadAsync () <0x359d2c8 + 0x000ea> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Blazor.Shared.ViewReportBase.OnInitializedAsync () [0x000a6] in C:\Users\Anthony\Source\Repos\AccessibilityApp\src\AccessibilityReportViewer\Blazor.Shared\ViewReport.razor.cs:34 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync () <0x2d12630 + 0x0013a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task taskToHandle) <0x2fdc928 + 0x000b6> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Program is set up as follows:

```cs
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            builder.Services.AddTransient<ICommonAccessTokenProvider, WebAssemblyAccessTokenProvider>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<AccessTokenProviderTokenCredential>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<Storage>();

            builder.Services.AddTransient(sp =>
                new HttpClient
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
                });

            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation");
            });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
```

and ultimatly the access token is accessed via:

```cs
    public class WebAssemblyAccessTokenProvider : ICommonAccessTokenProvider
    {
        private readonly IAccessTokenProvider _accessTokenProvider;
        private readonly NavigationManager _navigationManager;

        public WebAssemblyAccessTokenProvider(IAccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider, NavigationManager navigationManager)
        {
            _accessTokenProvider = accessTokenProvider;
            _navigationManager = navigationManager;
        }

        public async ValueTask<AccessToken> GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var result = await _accessTokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(new AccessTokenRequestOptions
            {
                Scopes = new string[] { "https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation" }
            });

            if (result.Status == AccessTokenResultStatus.RequiresRedirect)
            {
                _navigationManager.NavigateTo(result.RedirectUrl);
            }

            if (result.TryGetToken(out var accessToken))
            {
                return new AccessToken(accessToken.Value, accessToken.Expires);
            }
            throw new Exception("Couldn't get the access token");
        }

        public AccessToken GetToken(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Anyone seen this before or knows what's wrong?

UPDATE 1

Simple Source Repo: https://github.com/AnthonyDewhirst/BlazorADandBlobs

Any constructive help in anything else I have done wrong or could be done better is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you upload your demo in github without any confidential information and sensitive data.

Comment: HI Jason, not straight off, its in a private repo right now, but yes, I will get this done hopefully tonight (UK time)

Comment: Updated the OP with a simple repo link. Just a note: if I leave it a while, it seems to work (sort of) the first call but then every other call to get the blob fails. I am fairly sure I have got something wrong with the scopes, but think it might be something else as well

Comment: @Dewy did you manage to fix this? I'm getting the same error now. not with blazor though, just a normal console app